# my extjs grid is not showing json data in grid from local host

Tags: python, html, django, json, extjs

I am using django framework and getting some data from local host in json format like this:

```
[{"stu_name": "Aatir"}, {"stu_name": "Mohsin"}, {"stu_name": "Anil"}, {"stu_name": "Anwar"}, {"stu_name": "Amir"}]
```

now i want to use this data and want to show in extjs grid

my extjs files are as below:

**hmak.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Account Manager</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
Ext.application({
    requires : [ 'Ext.container.Viewport'],

    controllers: ['Users'],

    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'media/app',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'userlist'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

**Users.js(controller)**

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    stores: ['Users'],
    models: ['User'],

    views: ['user.List', 'user.Edit'],

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'viewport > userlist': {
                itemdblclick: this.editUser
            },
            'useredit button[action=save]': {
                click: this.updateUser
            }           
        });
    },

    updateUser: function(button) {
    var win    = button.up('window'),
        form   = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

    record.set(values);
    win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
    },

    editUser: function(grid, record) {
        var view = Ext.widget('useredit');

        view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    }
});
```

**List.js(view)**

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.userlist',

    store: 'Users',

    title : 'All Users',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = {
            fields: ["stu_name"]
        };

        this.columns = [
            {header: "stu_name",  dataIndex: "stu_name",  flex: 1}
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

**Edit.js(view)**

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.Edit', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.useredit',

    title : 'Edit User',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : "stu_name",
                        fieldLabel: "stu_name"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.buttons = [
            {
                text: 'Save',
                action: 'save'
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.close
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

**Users.js(store)**

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.User',

    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/task/'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

**User.js(model)**

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: ["stu_name"]
});
```

**viewport.js**

```
Ext.define('SI.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport'
});
```

and in my python I wrote:

```
def homePage(request):
    StuInfo.objects.all().values_list()
    return render_to_response('hmak.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

which in turn goes to hmak.html and from localhost/task (which I've define in the proxy) the data which it gets is in the json form as I've show you above json data

Now what is my problem that why my grid is not showing?
it just shows the header...

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You have to change the

```
Ext.define('SI.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport'
});
```

to

```
Ext.define('AM.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport'
});
```

and also deleting the store calling inside of the `initComponent` function.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the source of your problem:

```
this.store = {
        fields: ["stu_name"]
};
```

In the `initComponent` function, you are overwriting the store that you defined in the gridpanel class definition. Have you tried deleting that?